# Creating database views with NHibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate, view

Does any one know how to create a view from hibernate with the results of a criteria query?

We've got some legacy parts of our application that use views generated by the app for data retrieval and I like to tie the new NHibernate stuff into those for minimal friction.

I'd turn it into an extension method so I could eventually do stuff like this:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Thing>().CreateReportView().List();
```

Any ideas?

The existing process is like this:

```
SQLString = _bstr_t("SELECT name FROM User WHERE Retired = false");

...run the query process the results, then...

SQLStringView = _bstr_t(" \
  BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ") + ViewName + _bstr_t(" AS ") + SQLString;
```

So whenever we run this query we get a view that has the same data in it. I can't work out how to replicate this is hibernate though.

Comment: The views already exist in your database? Or does your app create them on the fly?

Comment: The app currently creates them on the fly using ADO. We're moving everything over to use NHibernate but need to maintain the views for the legacy stuff. So we need to create it when the query is executed.

Comment: @Matt Sharpe: I'm not sure I understand entirely; can you post some sample code explaining how your "only the fly" views work right now?

Comment: When the user runs a filter to view particular data the records are returned to them but the resultset is also written to a view, this is then used for reporting and for data access for certain screens. So everytime a user runs a filter (which is a SQL query) the resulting data is written into a view.

I need to do the same thing using Hibernate.

Comment: By "view", do you mean a view in the database, or something that exists on the application's side?  Also, is this for test code or for production code?

Comment: I mean a database view, I've added some sample code to clarify.

Comment: Saying the "result set is written to a view" makes no sense. It's only the query, the data could change and it would return a different result set later.

Comment: Yes it could, this is used for a filtering mechanism so the user selects a filter which returns data based on the criteria they specify. This 'active filter' is then used to provide data to various parts of the application.

Answer (score 2):

To create a view using NHibernate directly, take a look at the 'database-object' mapping element.

Ayende has a good example [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3947/nhibernate-mapping-lt-database-object-gt).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](https://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/mapping/mapping-the-same-class-to-a-view-and-a-table-using-entity-name) for an explanation of mapping an entity class to a view and a table. I'm not certain that you'll be able to dynamically create your views at runtime as you specified; but perhaps this can be done as part of the schema generation process using the database-object mapping?

Comment: The article isn't available anymore

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in filtering the data being returned, you may want to have a look at Nhibernate's filtering mechanisms; [here is a good article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/04/nhibernate-filters.aspx) outlining their usage.

Comment: Thanks for this but the filters are user created custom filters that cover the whole domain model and include things like Plan.Owner = {user}. This is all built up into a hibernate criteria query but to maintain the other parts of the application I need to generate this view. The view is used so the other parts of the technology stack (such as SSRS & COM) don't have to parse the saved filter and run the SQL themselves.